# Remove braces and word from column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this problem, I would like to remove the braces and a word from the column of a dataframe.
This is the column called Weight:

```
  Weight
{'weight': 24}
{'weight': 24}
{'weight': 22}
{'weight': 17}
{'weight': 17}
{'weight': 11}
{'weight': 21}
{'weight': 16}
....
```

What I want is this:

```
  Weight
   24
   24
   22
   17
   17
   11
   21
   16
   ....
```

How could this be done? Thanks

Comment: Please post any code you have tried so far.

Comment: `[row.get("weight") for row in df["Weight"]`, if your columns are actually dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have dictionares `{'weight': 24}`, not strings `"{'weight': 24}"`

---

Maybe it is strange but you can use `str` for this

```
df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].str['weight']

df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].str.get('weight')
```

You can also use `apply()` with `lambda`

```
df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].apply(lambda item: item['weight'])

df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].apply(lambda item: item.get('weight'))
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight':[
    {'weight': 24},
    {'weight': 24},
    {'weight': 22},
    {'weight': 17},
    {'weight': 17},
    {'weight': 11},
    {'weight': 21},
    {'weight': 16},
]})

print(df)

df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].str['weight']
#df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].str.get('weight')

#df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].apply(lambda item: item['weight'])
#df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].apply(lambda item: item.get('weight'))

print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also convert dictionary to `Series` and get `weight`

```
df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].apply(pd.Series).get('weight')

df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].apply(pd.Series).explode('weight')
```